# How to render right image with unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rendering

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXZjq.jpg) in unity3d "stratching" from center to corner of camera, how render it without such strange effects, like in real camera?

[image]

Comment: Not exactly clear what you're talking about - you're probably seeing the appearance of perspective, which actually does happen in real life; a "real camera" wouldn't be too far off from this (given the same FoV). If you want to flatten the image completely, try using an Orthographic camera rather than a Perspective camera - though be advised that this usually doesn't work too well for games played in 3D, due to the loss of depth perception from these kinds of visual cues.

Comment: Hi Аскер Чик.  I'm not seeing any problem --- did you try simply changing the field of view of the camera?  (the "lens length".)  just click on Camera and look in Inspector.

Comment: Current FOV - 90', this effect becomes invisible, if I set FOV 60, but it doesn't dissapear. I want to create soft to create sphere panorama and this effect bothers me. I cant join border pixels, they don't unite to each other

Comment: All this recangles have the same size; But they look different in different places of rendered image;